# How do I set the default selected color of the KendoEditor's foreColor tool?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-editor

I want to set the default color for the Kendo Editor's foreColor tool to "black". By default, the color is always "white".

Comment: can you use the stylesheets property: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/editor#configuration-stylesheets ?

Comment: I am not sure how to use stylesheets property to set the default value.

Comment: Demo here: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/editor/styles. you could try setting the css color attribute on the body tag.

Comment: I think you got my question wrong. I don't want to set the forecolor of the body tag. I want to set the default value of the foreColor tool in kendo editor's toolbar.

Comment: I understand now, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DontVoteMeDown has a great answer! However as soon as you click the dropdown arrow on the colorPicker, you lose the currently selected color.  You could save the current color to a variable and reload it each time the palette is opened. Then update the selected color on change:

```
    var curForeColor = "#000000";

    $("#editor").kendoEditor({
        tools: [{
            name: "foreColor",
        }]
    });


    var colorpicker = $("div.k-i-foreground-color").data("kendoColorPicker");
    colorpicker.value(curForeColor);

    colorpicker.bind("change", function(){
      curForeColor = colorpicker.value();
    });


    colorpicker.bind("open", function(){
      colorpicker.value(curForeColor);
    });
```

## **[DEMO](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/colorpicker#events-change)**

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var editor = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor");

$(editor.toolbar.element)
        .find("div.k-i-foreground-color")
        .data("kendoColorPicker")
            .value("#000000");
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/oVifed)

The *foreColor tool* is in fact a [ColorPicker](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/colorpicker/index) so you can set it's [`value`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/colorpicker#configuration-value) as soon as editor is created.

Comment: Nice +1. I expanded on yours to save and reload the current selection of color so it is not lost when opening the palette popup. If you open it and make no selection, you lose the black you had set...

Comment: Thanks for your response! Your solution works but if I open the color picker by clicking on the arrow the color is reverted back to white. Is there any solution to fix this?

Comment: @ezanker I realized that, but I didn't look further to fix it, I wasn't sure if that could be a problem.

Comment: I guess you could choose either functionality. I would not want the user to lose the default color if she opens the palette and then selects nothing. But of course it is all down to OP's requirements...

Comment: @ezanker It makes totally sense!!